# Catching jQuery noty with Katalon Studio

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, katalon-studio, noty

My AUT has a jQuery "noty" that appears after clicking on a button. ("Noty" is a jQuery plugin for message/notification creation.)

The message stays on screen for a couple of seconds and then goes away. I'm afraid that's to fast for methods such as  Katalon's `'WebUI.verifyElementPresent()'`. Is there another way to catch it with `Katalon Studio` or `Selenium`?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found a way to catch the `noty` messages, as described also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51168671/screenshot-with-katalon-and-chrome-headless-mode).

Here's my code:

```
import ru.yandex.qatools.ashot.AShot
import ru.yandex.qatools.ashot.Screenshot
import ru.yandex.qatools.ashot.coordinates.*
import ru.yandex.qatools.ashot.cropper.*

public class ScreenshotHelper {

  public void takeWebElementScreenshot(TestObject object) {
        WebElement element = WebUiCommonHelper.findWebElement(object, 20)
        WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver();
        String fileName = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmSSS").format(new Date())
        Screenshot screenshot = new AShot().takeScreenshot(driver, element)
        try {
            if (DriverFactory.getExecutedBrowser().getName()=='HEADLESS_DRIVER'){
            ImageIO.write(screenshot.getImage(),'PNG', new File("C:/Users/path_to_working_directory/ErrorScreenshots/HeadlessElementScreenshot"+"_"+fileName+".png"))
            } else {
            ImageIO.write(screenshot.getImage(),'PNG', new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/ErrorScreenshots/ElementScreenshot"+"_"+fileName+".png"))
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        }
}
```

This method gets called from another method of the same class:

```
public void catchNotyMessage(){

    TestObject noty_warning = new TestObject().addProperty('css', ConditionType.EQUALS, "div.noty_type_warning")
    TestObject noty_error = new TestObject().addProperty('css', ConditionType.EQUALS, "div.noty_type_error")

    if (WebUI.verifyElementPresent(noty_error, 1, FailureHandling.OPTIONAL)){
        this.takeWebElementScreenshot(noty_error)
    }
    else if (WebUI.verifyElementPresent(noty_warning, 1, FailureHandling.OPTIONAL)){
        this.takeWebElementScreenshot(noty_warning)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a way to handle this situation:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait as WebDriverWait

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf('your noty WebElement that you have to identify before') )
```